# Calculate percent composition from XPS?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, spectroscopy, composition

I have an XPS graph and was wondering how to calculate percent composition. I do have the percent compositions that were determined from the graph, but I don't know how they were found. For reference, I am looking at a N 1s XPS plot, shown below (part C):

[image: XPS of structure]

I had tried calculating the composition by the areas under the curves for N 1s, but when I did I got an equal area for both the pyridinic (pink area) and graphitic (orange area) Nitrogens, which is not correct as the graphitic Nitrogen has a much smaller composition. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The coloured curves are made by least squares fitting of 3  gaussian curves to the data and the area under each calculated. This area then can be made a fraction or percentage of total area.